# Is there a way to convert Mongoose document ObjectId to string?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I've to filter the document keys for different users based on the user roles/permissions.

For example, 1 user can get `secretCode` while others not.

Converting the document to an object does convert the doc to a plain object but the ObjectIds are still objects (bson type).

I can try `_id.toString()` but I've multiple fields with the objectId. So it will be kind of hard-coding in all the fields. Plus, I'll also have to validate if the value is not null, else .toString() is not a function will pop up.

Another way is to use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) but this synchronous and unnecessary computation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at [Mongoose toJson() and toObject()](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-tojson-toobject-transform-with-subdocuments/).

Comment: I've read the documentation including `toJSON` and `toObject` with their options.

It does convert it to the POJO but the objectId is still a bson type object.

Comment: in that case, you can define another property in your schema as `Id` and then in the getter of the property call a function which will convert the original `_id` to `_id.toString()` as: `Id: {
        type: String,
        getter: function(val) { return this._id.toString(); },
        unique: true
    }`

Comment: Yes, but what if I've 4 keys (including _id). Not a good thing to create multiple keys.

Comment: well then the only left option is to create a custom schema type have a look at [ObjectIdAsString](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2352#issuecomment-58395639) plus just a suggestion there is a package available for handling the permissions with `mongoose` as [mongoose-rbac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-rbac).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm probably going with transformation or virtuals. 

You should not be using this npm module. It is 5 years old with only a handful of downloads/week. Did you hear about "electron-native-notify"?

I avoid unnecessary npm modules most of the time. BTW, I'm using 'access-control'.